# Free Style Guide / Brand Guideline Templates

Tags: branding, identity, template

Does anyone know where / if I can download any for free? It's more just the content that I'm after, I could then tailor that and the design of the document itself to each branding job that I work on.

Writing isn't my strong point so a template would be a good starting point I believe.

Comment: Easy: search Google, download, study. Most significant organisations post their brand guideline online to facilitate more consistent use. Use these as your template tailoring the creative / direction to your own client. In my day (cough) we had no internet so as students we were encouraged to write to organisations and ask for their guide.  Example: ŠKODA AUTO https://logoblink.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/skoda-brand-guideline.pdf  (Note: not official link and 2003 version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

www.designcuts.com/product/complete-professional-designers-toolkit/

Now, it's not free, I know – but the free stuff rarely is of any use anway, and if you plan on doing this thing professionally and for a longer period of time, $29 is very little money very well invested.

Keep an eye out for other deals on designcuts. They're not paying me to say this, but they always have great deals on almost anything design related ;)

hope this was helpful

Comment: thanks, I think I'll go with this! a small price to pay really, I'll most likely just recreate the document myself and paste whatever text / content I need from this

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I've ever seen a template. Might have better luck looking at actual companies. Large companies and Universities sometimes have their brand guidelines available on their websites.

Companies:

- [DuPont Branding](http://www.dupont.com/content/dam/assets/products-and-services/membranes-films/assets/DEC-Kapton-Trademark-Guidelines.pdf) (Couldn't find their full book but might be there somewhere, I know it exists cause they've emailed it to me before)
- [Volvo Penta Branding](http://comportal.penta.volvo.se/ID_StandardPage/Index?page=137)

And then as I mentioned lots of Universities, maybe even all:

- [Colorado School of Mines Branding](http://inside.mines.edu/Mines-Logos-and-Branding)
- [NYU Branding](http://www.nyu.edu/employees/resources-and-services/media-and-communications/styleguide.html)
- [UMinn Branding](https://www.ur.umn.edu/brand/)

Comment: thanks! I did go with a similar approach a few times in the past, however I think I'll go down the paid route for a template afterall as it appears to be the most straightforward approach... and then simply copy/paste whatever content I need from it into my own guideline documents